Point and click exploration game from the 1990s
Facts I'm confident of:

I never played the full game, but I played a demo of it some time between 1994-1998.
It was for Windows 95.
It was a first-person point-and-click adventure game set in some advanced underground ruins.
The rooms were pre-animated rather than full 3D.
The game starts in the dark, and one of the first puzzles is operating a bizarre light switch that has sun and moon symbols on it.
There was a mosaic puzzle where you must move tiles around and they change shape/symbol when you get them to the right place.
There was a pool of acid with a moving platform in it.
There was a music puzzle where you heard a scale of notes play, and you had to replicate it by clicking on keys.
After unlocking a door, the demo ended, and there was a montage of pictures from the full game including various magic/advanced ancient technology elements.

Facts I'm less confident of:

There were a lot of green and gold colours.
I think it was probably distributed by a magazine demo disc.
I had previously thought it may have been included in the "Manhattan Space Station - Odyssey" games for windows demo disc, but I have since found lists of games on that disc, and I didn't recognise the game I'm looking for.
I believe the story was about a priest/archaeologist who fell down a cave into the ruins of an hyper-advanced ancient civilisation.
The ancient civilisation had an obsession with logic and geometrical puzzles and astronomical symbols.

I have never seen anything that looked like the full game, and I don't know if it was even a finished product.

Perhaps Entombed Enhanced (1997) by WizardWorks?  The linked site has an image of the sliding-symbol puzzle.

It's available on myabandonware.com if you're still interested in playing it.
